# How do you get information about the physical drives in a HP Smart Array RAID volume

Tags: linux, raid, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I've got a HP DL380 running and I know one of the drives has failed.  (I have a cron job running cciss_vol_status) The OS doesn't see the individual drives, it just sees one big volume called /dev/cciss/c0d0.  Is there any way I can figure out the model number of the physical drives?  Also is there any way to make the LED on the the failed drive blink so I can identify which one it is?  I'm hoping there's a way of doing this from linux without rebooting to get to the BIOS menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How do you know one of the drives has failed?  On our ProLiant servers the LEDs on the individual drive trays that turn orange and flash angrily when the drive fails.  On your DL380 if one of the drives has failed it should be giving you a visual cue on the font of the unit.

To get more information, you could try the [Array Configuration Utility Software](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/index.html) available from HP -- I haven't used the Linux version but we sure have had good luck with SmartArray controllers on Windows for over a decade, going back to the Compaq versions.  It's one of the those things that's "just worked" like it's supposed to for us.

HTH.

Comment: haha.. I love, `flash angrily'. I've always thought that, but nver come across anyone else who's verbalized that. Upvote for that :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the smartmontools (specifically smartctl), you could do the following (assuming the DL380 max of 6 drives (0-5)):

```
for i in `seq 0 5`
do
    smartctl -d cciss,$i -a /dev/cciss/c0d0
done
```

Comment: The best thing with cciss driver in Linxu is that it passes the Disk SMART data right through.

Comment: Of course, if you have an MSA60 (or many) chained to your RAID controller, you'll have more disks to check with smartctl.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you haven't installed the various tools from the HP PSP/'Proliant Support Pack'?, if you have then just browse to the SMH/'System Management Homepage' (http://hostname:2301).

If you haven't then have you setup the iLO/'Integrated Lights Out' port? if so then you'll be able to look in the IML/'Insight Management Log' in that. If you haven't set it up just look at the label on the machine with the serial number on, it'll list the iLO administrator password - record this, connect a pc to the iLO port, then when you reboot the machine next time go into setup, set the iLO IP/NM/DG, HTTP**S** to that IP from the laptop, userid=administrator/password=what from the label and it's all GUI from there.

Feel free to ask any more questions directly.

Regards,

Phil.