# Getting Proliant P212 disk SMART diagnostics in Centos 6.2/RHEL

Tags: raid, redhat, hp-proliant, smart, raid-controller

Does anyone know how I can monitor (either gui or shell) the health status of my SATA disks via the P212 (256Mb) controller card of my ProLiant ML110 G6 ? I've currently got Centos 6.2 64bit installed but don't see how to show,say, the current SMART temperature values of the RAIDed SATA disks. On ubuntu I believe I have used some sensors daemon or similar in the past but not with P212 (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [ProLiant management agents for your server model](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=4344075&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D4344075%257CprodSeriesId%253D3984625%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

The hp-snmp-agents package will provide some of what you need, but the [Array Configuration Utility](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/index.html) (especially the [hpacucli](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=468780&prodNameId=468781&swEnvOID=4004&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-c029e034abc54269a327a9b9c7) program) will be the most helpful. Since this is a 100-series server, installing the HP agents may be a bit too heavy. They're really optimized for the higher-end models.

If you're looking for a quick way to check RAID status (which is more important than SMART status in this case), try the [cciss_vol_status script](http://freecode.com/projects/ccissvolstatus).

Also see:

[How do I get my HP servers to email me when a drive fails?](https://serverfault.com/questions/342383/how-do-i-get-my-hp-servers-to-email-me-when-a-drive-fails)

[How do you get information about the physical drives in a HP Smart Array RAID volume](https://serverfault.com/questions/19824/how-do-you-get-information-about-the-physical-drives-in-a-hp-smart-array-raid-vo)

Edit:

cciss_vol_status output:

```
[root@Fruity ~]# cat /proc/scsi/scsi 
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: hp       Model: DVD A  DS8A5LH   Rev: 1HE4
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: P410i            Rev: 5.14
  Type:   RAID                             ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 01
  Vendor: HP       Model: LOGICAL VOLUME   Rev: 5.14
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

I tried `/dev/sg0`, `/dev/sg1` and `/dev/sg2`... I actually have a disk reporting a SMART issue...

```
[root@Fruity ~/cciss_vol_status-1.09]# ./cciss_vol_status -s /dev/sg1
/dev/sda: (Smart Array P410i) RAID 1 Volume 0 status: OK. 
         connector 1I box 1 bay 3     STEC    Z16IZF2D-200UCM    STM000143959     E123 S.M.A.R.T. predictive failure.
```

Comment: many thanks for this very prompt reply. I have now got the HP SNMP Agents and system health cli installed and can now do "# hpacucli controller slot=3 physicaldrive all show", for instance, and the output information does include the drive temperatures. Then I installed the cciss software but as yet cannot figure the name of my raid device to tell it to query. cat /proc/scsi/scsi show the RAID as scsi4 chan 0 id 0 lun 0 and ls -l /sys/class/scsi_generic lists sg0,sg1 and sg2. No doubt someone can point me at what device to use for cciss_vol_status -s /dev/,,,,

Comment: It's RHEL6 under the `hpsa` driver, so... `/dev/sdX` is the block device. I just checked on another server and my output is added to my answer above.

Comment: Good. Please mark this as the answer.